# how to build a web service using tomcat and then use it in android ksoap2

Tags: android, tomcat, service, web, ksoap2

I'm about to develop a web service using TomCat and an application on Android that uses it (using ksoap2). I found a lot of tutorials showing how to use an existing web service with ksoap2 on android, and I also found a lot of tutorials showing how to create a web service with TomCat. However, I couldn't find any tutorial that shows how to create a web service with TomCat and then use it on android (again, with ksoap2).
I tried to do it myself of course, using two computers that were connected to the same network (different IPs), but I didn't know what values to put in the namespace, method_name, url and the soap_action. Each value I've tried led me to an error on the client's side...

Do you know where I can find a tutorial that explains how to do the above? or perhaps someone here can just tell me how to do it?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2ksoap/

Comment: I couldn't manage to understand how to use it and it seems to fail... any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

check this url http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/webservice-from-android.aspx

```
    NAMESPACE = "your web service package get this in wsdl";
    URL = "wsdl path";
    SOAP_ACTION = nameof;//portType name="" in wsdl;
    METHOD_NAME_Rate = "web service methodname";
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME_Rate);
    request.addProperty("webservice method parameter1", agr1);
    request.addProperty("webservice method parameter1", arg2);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL, 10000);
    try {
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        SoapObject resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
        r = resultsRequestSOAP.getProperty("return").toString();            

    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {

    } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {            

    } catch (IOException e) {

    } finally {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The [links section](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/Links) on the ksoap2-android web site has a bunch of tutorials linked including one for server side stuff using Java. Specifically check out Rodricks site with e.g. [this article](http://roderickbarnes.com/blog/droid-chronicles-web-services-part-1).